# Performance hints for custom series

Tags: performance, echarts

Echarts [custom series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-custom.type) are really flexibel and convenient.
But unfortunately the performance is really slow (compared to the "native" series).

e.g. here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/g7qm9wuL/24/) (using echarts 4.8.0) that draws 5 custom series (with only 500 points each).
To test with more data, you can simply adjust the variables at the top of the jsfiddle code:

```js
/**
 * the number of data-samples
 */
var dataCount = 2000;

/**
 * we create one custom series for each item in the csColors array
 */
var csColors = [
  '#FF9800', '#9C27B0', '#512DA8', '#4CAF50', '#448AFF'
  // , '#d32f2f', '#F1C40F', '#8bc6ff', '#00bc91', '#992f1c'
];
```

Even with this little data, zoomig (using the mouse wheel) or using the brush is already really slow.
For our application we would need up to 10 charts with ~5 series and 1k data samples each. And with that many samples the custom series is just not usable, because rendering takes way too long.

- Any ideas how we could improve the performance?

  - e.g. when we use the brush it seems that almost every mouse-move redraws the whole series: I guess it may be related to the [emphasis settings](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-custom.emphasis): is there a way to deactivate this?
- Or is there maybe another way we could get fast custom series (i.e. directly draw on the canvas, ..)?